# Getting the wired network name and security level on Windows

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, networking, wmi

And by this question I mean the user assigned names windows lets you type in like: "My home network"  "Basement" "Garage" not the ssid (though I would also like to read that one for the wifi connections)

and I especially want to read the windows security levels that can be chosen for networks: Home/Office/Public

I want to use this information to switch programs on and off automatically when connecting to various networks.

**Update:**
Thanks to the answer of @Damien_The_Unbeliever I was able to solve my question and find the following information, I hope it will help others too:

- [Network awareness in windows 7 and vista (MSDN, Unmanaged)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264321%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Windows API Code Pack (Microsoft, managed wrapper for
  NetworkListManager and others)](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack)
- [How to use the windows NLM API to get notified of new network
  connectivity (Codeproject, Managed)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34650/How-to-use-the-Windows-NLM-API-to-get-notified-of)

Comment: "the" wired network may not exist in some circumstances - some people may be connected to multiple networks simultaneously.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that is not a problem I have that same situation in my house, in that case I would like to iterate through the list of connections and check each.

Comment: This doesn't answer the stated question but the firewall already handles different profiles for different networks allowing different applications to be accessable. You may also be able to use the task scheduler to detect to pick up on the event log entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use the [Network List Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The Microsoft Windows networking environment allows multihomed computers to connect to several networks simultaneously. There may be multiple wireless networks available along with LAN and dial-up connections. Network List Manager identifies available networks and returns network attribute data to the application.

It's a COM API, I'm not aware of a managed equivalent.

Comment: Ahh that's what I wanted to find :)